# Are GROUP BY and/or UNION appropriate? Or should I just use a nested SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am interested in "cross-referencing" two columns and return two pieces of information:

The columns are `saddr`,`daddr`,`sbytes`, `dbytes`.

I would like to find `DISTINCT` `saddr` and match them with `DISTINCT` `daddr`, then `SUM` the `sbytes` and `dbytes`.

I would also like to simply find the count of records that exist per `saddr` per `daddr` (given an `daddr` N records match this `saddr`).

For those of you who may be interested in context, I am using a package called [argus](http://qosient.com/argus/), and its client [rasqlinsert](http://qosient.com/argus/man/man1/rasqlinsert.1.pdf) to build a database of network traffic flows.

Thanks,

Matt

[edit]

Sample data:

```
SELECT saddr,daddr,sbytes,dbytes FROM argus.argus2012K17 limit 5;

   '01:80:c2:00:00:0a', '20:fd:f1:74:36:96', 194, 0
   '01:80:c2:00:00:0a', '20:fd:f1:74:36:b6', 194, 0
   '192.168.100.11', '212.243.210.210', 120, 120
   '192.168.100.11', '212.243.210.210', 422, 3667
   '192.168.100.23', '99.248.99.240', 132, 0
```

Desired result:

```
saddr, daddr, how many records found where they both exist, sum of all sbytes in these records, sum of all dbytes in these records

    '01:80:c2:00:00:0a', '20:fd:f1:74:36:96', 2, 388, 0
    '192.168.100.11', '212.243.210.210', 2, 542, 3787
    '192.168.100.23', '99.248.99.240', 1, 132, 0
```

I think I'm having the most trouble wrapping my head around the "where they both exist" aspect of the query.

[edit2]

I've concluded that I just need to spend time reading and gain understanding of [GROUP BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.com/sql-group-by-sql-tutorial/) and perform a nested query to get the info I'd like.  However, if anyone has any more input it would be appreciated.

[edit 3]
Solution:

```
SELECT saddr, daddr, SUM(sbytes), SUM(dbytes), count(saddr) FROM argus.argus2012K17 GROUP BY saddr, daddr;
```

Returns:

```
SELECT saddr, daddr, SUM(sbytes), SUM(dbytes), count(saddr) FROM argus.argus2012K17 where saddr='01:80:c2:00:00:0a' GROUP BY saddr, daddr;
    '01:80:c2:00:00:0a', '20:fd:f1:74:36:96', 326114, 0, 1681
    '01:80:c2:00:00:0a', '20:fd:f1:74:36:b6', 326114, 0, 1681
```

Hell yea.

```
SELECT stime, saddr, daddr, SUM(sbytes), SUM(dbytes), count(saddr) FROM argus.argus2012K17 WHERE stime BETWEEN 1337187600 AND 1337187700 GROUP BY saddr, daddr;
```

Comment: Are you asking what's more optimal? Or most readable? Or best practice?

Comment: I think I get what you ask about `GROUP BY`, but I don't see where `UNION` comes in here.

Comment: Thanks Keyser.  I'm not concerned so much with readability, but optimal (resource cost -wise), and best practice are both concerns.  Your comment implies there are several ways to get this done, which is good, as I simply don't understand any.

Comment: Jirka: I suppose I figured an option would be to create a temporary table, populated by a nested query, to query, but I suppose `as` would be is the same and much less costly versus a `DROP` followed by a `UNION`?

Comment: @mbrownnyc - `UNION` concatenates two query results, and optionally removes duplicates.  I don't see what two queries you would want to union.  What exactly do you want to SUM the bytes across?  One sum per one source and dest address pair?  I extended my answer - that's how I currently understand your question.

Comment: You might get better responses if you included some sample data and desired result. It will go a long way in clarifying your question. For example its not clear to me what you mean by "SUM the Bytes" especially since you're doing distinct

Comment: Thanks for replying, Conrad and Jirka.  I have updated the original question with sample data and the outcome I wish to be returned.  This may help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with using these constructs, supposing they give you the results you want.  Simulating them with nested SELECTs will give you either the same or worse performance.

I think you simply need this:

```
SELECT saddr, daddr, SUM(bytes) GROUP BY saddr, daddr
```

Comment: How does this "... find DISTINCT saddr and **match** them with DISTINCT daddr". Also no From clause?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need a driving table and a group by.  SQL cannot produce the rows with 0 cnt using the group by alone:

```
select driver.saddr, driver.daddr, coalesce(t.sumbytes) as bytes
from (select saddr, daddr
      from (select distinct saddr from t) cross join
           (select distinct daddr from t)
     ) driver left outer join
     (select saddr, daddr, sum(byets) as sumbytes
      from t
      group by saddr, daddr
     ) as tsum
     on t.saddr = tsum.saddr and t.daddr = tsum.daddr
```

This statement gets all combinations of saddr and daddr.  It then joins this to the sum of the bytes.  The outer select produces 0 when no sum is present.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is looking for something that would include something like `SELECT s.saddr , d.daddr from t s JOIN t d on s.saddr = d.daddr` but the question isn't clear enough.